# How do identify the name of an id inside a div?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to write a program that identifies the id inside a div and gives back the name of the id.

```
<div id="page0" class="subpage">
      <h2 id="RM10129"> Cold Startes </h2>
        <div id="RM10129" class="menubox"></div>
        <div id="RM10129" class="menubox"></div>
      <h2 id="RM10130"> Main </h2>
        <div id="RM10130" class="menubox"></div>
        <div id="RM10130" class="menubox"></div>
```

I want my program to return the ids "RM10129" and "RM10130". Is that possible with xpath?

Comment: What package are you using to parse the HTML currently? Show us the code you have so far. Thanks.

Comment: #include <std_warnings_about_parsing_html_as_xml>

Answer (score 1):

You can use `starts-with()` to check that `id` starts with `RM`:

```
//div[@id='page0']/div[starts-with(@id, 'RM') and @class = 'menubox']/@id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [**`xpath`**](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html) as part of [**`lxml`**](http://lxml.de/index.html) lib:

```
import lxml.html

ttt = """<div id="page0" class="subpage">
      <h2 id="RM10129"> Cold Startes </h2>
        <div id="RM10129" class="menubox"></div>
        <div id="RM10129" class="menubox"></div>
      <h2 id="RM10130"> Main </h2>
        <div id="RM10130" class="menubox"></div>
        <div id="RM10130" class="menubox"></div>"""


page = lxml.html.fromstring(ttt)

print page.xpath('.//div[@class="menubox"]/@id')
```

And continue further verification.

Answer (score 0):

This xpath would return you all DIV ids inside of DIV with ID page0.

```
//div[@id="page0"]/div/@id
```